# C++ object assignment to NULL

Tags: c++, boost, null

I was looking at some code that uses [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function.html) and have a question about how code can be written to allow assignment to NULL.  I tried to track down the corresponding Boost code, but was unable to.  Basically, what makes this possible?

```
boost::function<void()> func;
func = NULL;
```

EDIT: The following doesn't compile for me though, so how do they prevent this too?

```
func = 1;
```

Comment: If your question was about the underlying implementation, then you need to remember that `function` is a polymorphic object that keeps the pointer to the actual function (object). That pointer naturally can be null.

Comment: @Gene, I guess my question more specifically is about implementing assignment to NULL in general, not really the semantics behind `boost::function`.  What you said makes sense though, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By operator overloading with pointer parameter. From boost sources:

```
#ifndef BOOST_NO_SFINAE
   self_type& operator=(clear_type*)
   {
     this->clear();
     return *this;
   }
#endif
```

This doesn't mean that "func" itself is NULL, indeed you can access its own functions. Following code compiles and doesn't crash.

```
TEST_F(CppTest, BoostFunctions) {
    boost::function<void()> func;
    func = NULL;
    ASSERT_TRUE(func==NULL);
    ASSERT_FALSE(func.has_trivial_copy_and_destroy());
}
```

Comment: Is this the same mechanism that prevents `func = 1`, do you know?

Comment: @JaredC: Yes.  NULL, 0, and other null pointer constants can be converted to a clear_type*, but 1 cannot.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  This also seems to imply that this 'trick' will only work for objects that represent pointers, or where assignment to a pointer is well-defined.  I guess this won't work in the more general case where you want `obj = NULL` to invoke `obj.reset()` or the like, huh?

Comment: @JaredC: It works only if `obj` is an instance of a class that supports such an idiom. `boost::shared_ptr<T>`  is another example.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what exactly you are trying to do but this could help:

```
boost::function<void()> *pFunc;
pFunc = NULL;
```

Btw, in C++ you mostly write 0 or nullptr instead of NULL.

Comment: except that you would probably never want to create function object dynamically.

Comment: You have misunderstood.  I don't believe the OP wants a pointer to boost::function.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030437/c-object-assignment-to-null/5030666#5030666

Answer (score 1):

`boost::function` can accept a pointer to a function in its assignment operator.  A pointer can be a valid pointer or `NULL` (meaning 0).  The reason you get an error when trying to pass an `int` is that you cannot assign an integer to a pointer.  It is like trying to do the following:

```
char* c = 1;
```

Which won't compile either.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982519.aspx) the std::function has an assignment operator from `nullptr_t`

Comment: That looks VC++ specific, do you know if that is portable C++?  I am using linux and boost.

Comment: @JaredC -- it's not VC++ specific, it's C++0x specific.

Comment: My bad.  I'm not using C++0x currently though.  I'll keep this in mind though.